# MS Access continuous form bound checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, continuous-forms

I have a situation where i need to set only one ID as default on a continuous form. It does not seem to be easy to do so.
Pls have a look on attached image, it is allowing me to choose more than one.
I have tried with radio button, it does not work either

[image: sample]

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. You will need to manually handle the selection, e.g. clear all selections and then apply the current selection once clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the `RecordsetClone` of the form:

```vb
Private Sub IsDefault_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset
    
    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If
    
    If Me!IsDefault.Value = True Then
        ' Deselect other records.
        Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
        rs.MoveFirst
        While Not rs.EOF
            If rs!Id.Value <> Me!Id.Value Then
                If rs!IsDefault.Value = True Then
                    rs.Edit
                        rs!IsDefault.Value = False
                    rs.Update
                End If
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
        rs.Close
        
        Me!SomeOtherControl.SetFocus
        Me!IsDefault.Enabled = False
        Me!IsDefault.Locked = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim Ready           As Boolean
    Dim NewRecord       As Boolean
    
    NewRecord = Me.NewRecord
    
    If NewRecord Then
        Me!IsDefault.DefaultValue = Not CBool(Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)
        Me!SomeOtherControl.SetFocus
    Else
        Ready = Not Me!IsDefault.Value
    End If
    
    ' The selected record cannot be deselected.
    ' Deselect by selecting another record.
    Me!IsDefault.Enabled = Ready
    Me!IsDefault.Locked = Not Ready
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! works nicely but i need to click twice to check the other checkbox

Comment: That's probably because the first click only makes the selected record current, thus enables the checkbox to receive the second click. Perhaps you don't need to disable the checkbox.

Comment: I don't think you need to disable outside of the current record - you can only edit in the current record anyway.

Comment: @Andre: The purpose is to - when marked as selected and all other are unselected - to disable the option to unselect that record, as one record always must be selected. So, to unselect that record, goto another record and mark that as selected. It's like an option group.